# sed replace doesn't work with particular regexp

Tags: sed

I'm trying to make a replace with `sed`:

```
cat myfile | grep router | sed -e 's/Custom devices \(DiY\) \[CC2530 router\]\(http:\/\/ptvo\.info\/cc2530&#45;based&#45;zigbee&#45;coordinator&#45;and&#45;router&#45;112\/\) \(CC2530\.ROUTER\)/CC2530 router/g'
```

The output of the piped `grep` is:

```
<text text-anchor="middle" x="455.5" y="-31.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#ffffff">Custom devices (DiY) [CC2530 router](http://ptvo.info/cc2530&#45;based&#45;zigbee&#45;coordinator&#45;and&#45;router&#45;112/) (CC2530.ROUTER)</text>
```

This works well:

```
cat myfile | grep Xiaomi | sed -e 's/Xiaomi Aqara temperature, humidity and pressure sensor/AqaraTHP/g'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Change `\(DiY\)` to `(DiY)`, remove all backslashes before `(` and `)`. Or, just replace `-e` with `-E` You are using a POSIX ERE expression with the POSIX BRE engine. See https://ideone.com/YF8QL5

Comment: and save yourself the headache of escaping `/` chars in `https://....` by using a different character to delimit the `s/txt/rep/` like `s@txt@rep@`. Use a char that is not in your `txt` or `rep` of course. If you're using MacOS, you'll need to escape that initial char, i.e. `sed 's\@txt@rep@'` .Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page says that

> **-e command**
>
> Append the editing commands specified by the command argument to the
>   list of commands.

You need to use `-E` or `-r` option (whichever is supported by your sed):

```
cat myfile | grep router | sed -E 's/Custom devices \(DiY\) \[CC2530 router\]\(http:\/\/ptvo\.info\/cc2530&#45;based&#45;zigbee&#45;coordinator&#45;and&#45;router&#45;112\/\) \(CC2530\.ROUTER\)/CC2530 router/g'
```

With `-E`, `\(` denotes a plain `(` symbol and `(` is the indicator of capturing group.